# Class with Map<Key,Class>

Tags: data-structures, collections, hashmap, logic, trie

I am learning Trie and am looking at the Trie Implementation that has Node with HashMap implementation.
I do not understand the part where **the TrieNode has a children that is a Map of Character and Trienode(Itself)**. **Does this not create an infinte loop where the TrieNode calls the children and Children calls the Trienode again and so on?**. How does this part of the code work?

```
// Private class
private class TrieNode {
    Map<Character, TrieNode> children;
    boolean endOfWord;

    // Constructor
    public TrieNode() {
        children = new HashMap<>();
        endOfWord = false;
    }
}// End of inner class
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line `Map<character, Trienode> children;`, the `TrieNode` is just a type name. When this map is instantiated (in the constructor), no `TrieNode` objects are created/called, but the `TrieNode` type information is used to correctly create the map.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add a string to the Trie, you need to creat the link between character and trieNode,by this way you can find the next trieNode throuth this character value.just think about the first character is a edge,and the second trieNode is a Node,you can find the children node by find the true edge.
Besides, I think it is not nesscessory to **children = new HashMap<>();** ,you can just **children = null;**

```
   public TrieNode() {
        children = new HashMap<>();
        endOfWord = false;
    }
```